# Contact 7 form is causing error in my website afrter updated to the latest wordpress 5.0

Tags: wordpress, logging, error-handling, contact-form-7

My website is missing some of the styling after upgrading to version 5.0, I received an email from wordpress with this error when I check the website yesterday it was not structured well and also missing styling.

I haven't come across this error so when I got it I tried to delete the plugin contact form 7 form and re-installed it again but the problem is still there.

This is the message I got from the logs

```
Error Details
=============
An error of type E_PARSE was caused in line 352 of the file /home/****/public_html/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/modules/constant-contact.php. Error message: syntax error, unexpected 'pu' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST)
```

here is the function in question

```
          public function create_contact( $properties ) {
        $endpoint = 'https://api.cc.email/v3/contacts';

        $request = array(
            'method' => 'POST',
            'headers' => array(
                'Accept' => 'application/json',
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            ),
            'body' => json_encode( $properties ),
        );

        $response = $this->remote_request( $endpoint, $request );

        if ( 400 <= (int) wp_remote_retrieve_response_code( $response ) ) {
            if ( WP_DEBUG ) {
                $this->log( $endpoint, $request, $response );
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
```

line 352 is where the function start.

I have removed public and clear cache but still the site is not fixed.

There is also an empty __construct in line 638 in the same file.

```
public function __construct() {
    }
```

I hope someone can help me with this as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I head to go to the cPanel and delete the file contact form 7 in wp-content > plugins manually after that I downloaded the plugin and uploaded it in the plugins session.

After that I cleared cache and refreshed my website and it was back in actions.

Answer (score 0):

Could u post line 352 in which the error occurs?

Comment: Try it without public, just function.

Comment: Okay I will try that later on. Thank you hope it works.

Comment: You're missing a curly bracket to end the function.

Comment: If that's not the problem check for any misspellings since E_PARSE errors are mostly related to wrong syntax.

Comment: Where is it suppose to be ? the curly bracket?

Comment: At the end, to end the function

Comment: this is the whole function ** function create_contact( $properties ) {
  $endpoint = 'https://api.cc.email/v3/contacts';

  $request = array(
   'method' => 'POST',
   'headers' => array(
    'Accept' => 'application/json',
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
   ),
   'body' => json_encode( $properties ),
  );

  $response = $this->remote_request( $endpoint, $request );

  if ( 400 <= (int) wp_remote_retrieve_response_code( $response ) ) {
   if ( WP_DEBUG ) {
    $this->log( $endpoint, $request, $response );
   }

   return false;
  }
 }**

Comment: Sorry can't think of any other solutions.